# Sum 2 columns of pandas DataFrame with a row condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
    A   B   C
0   0   -2  1
1   1   -1  2
2   2   0   3
3   3   1   0
4   4   2   5
```

I want to get a new column such that it picks elements from B if B is positive (>0) otherwise picks elements from C

```
    A   B   C    D
0   0   -2  1    1
1   1   -1  2    2 
2   2   0   3    3
3   3   1   0    1  
4   4   2   5    5
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want? Does it have to sum B and C (eg row 4 -> 2 + 5 is not 5), or just the maximum of both columns?

Comment: I want to get a new column such that it picks elements from B if B is positive (>0) otherwise picks elements from C

Comment: Also what should be done to get something like D(x) = B(x) +C(x) if B(x)>0 else C(x)

Comment: Your row 4 does not follow this.

Comment: Yeah That was a follow up question. May be I will creste a new question and post it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Boolean mask:

```
In [14]: df[df[['B', 'C']] > 0].max(1)
Out[14]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    5
dtype: float64

In [15]: df['D'] = df[df[['B', 'C']] > 0].max(1)
```

Comment: Thanks ! any ideas how to do D(x) = B(x) +C(x) if B(x)>0 else C(x) efficiently